# Grep & cut for if condition

Tags: bash, caching, grep, cut

I would like to check if this data still exists in my cache file 
My cache file(check.cache) example :

```
10.0.0.0,tcp,80,127.0.0.1
10.0.0.1,tcp,443,127.0.0.2
10.0.0.2,tcp,80,127.0.0.3
```

I check if ip source, protocol and port exist and i want to compare the public ip i get with a client with a public ip in cache

```
_PUBLIC_IP=127.0.0.1
_CACHE_FILE=/var/lib/check.cache
_CHECK_IP="$ip_source,$_PROTOCOL,$_PORT"
          if grep -q "$_CHECK_IP" "$_CACHE_FILE"; then
               _OLD_PUBLIC_IP=$(cat $_CACHE_FILE | cut -d, -f4)
               echo "INFO: $_OLD_PUBLIC_IP"
               if [[ $_OLD_PUBLIC_IP != $_PUBLIC_IP ]]; then
                 echo "CRITICAL: The public IP has changed it was $_OLD_PUBLIC_IP and changed to $_PUBLIC_IP."
               else
                 _log "OK: no change for IP addresses."
               fi
           else
               echo $_DATA_CACHE >> $_CACHE_FILE
          fi
```

But it returns a critical error even though the value exists for the first line in my cache file because it retrieves all public ip's from the cache file at once 
Example:

```
INFO: 127.0.0.1 127.0.0.2 127.0.0.3
CRITICAL: The public IP has changed it was 127.0.0.1 127.0.0.2 127.0.0.3 and changed to 127.0.0.1
```

I would like my condition to check if one of the ip in the cache file is equal to the public ip to return that there is no error

Any pointers in the right direction would be of help. Thanks

Comment: Does the command `echo "TEST: $_OLD_PUBLIC_IP"` print out one line only?

Comment: i have failed it's echo "INFO: $_OLD_PUBLIC_IP"

Comment: Does it print one line only or not?

Comment: Your code is incomplete.  Ex. `echo $_DATA_CACHE >> $_CACHE_FILE`, you did not specify what `$_DATA_CACHE` is.  One thing for sure, `_OLD_PUBLIC_IP=$(cat $_CACHE_FILE | cut -d, -f4)` will give you all IP addresses contained in your check.cache file.  You should instead do `_OLD_PUBLIC_IP=$(grep "$_CHECK_IP" "$_CACHE_FILE" | cut -d, -f4)`.  This will give you only 1 IP address, so your `if` works.